# Linked CSS stylesheet only partly connecting

Tags: css

EDIT/UPDATE: This happens every day. I write code and it doesn't work, then I open it the next day and it does work. Why is this happening?
I'm using Sublime Text 2 to write the code, using XAMPP/Apache to run it, and Chrome to view it.

I'm creating a basic web page and this is what I have so far

home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Touch of Dazzle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_page">
        <? 
            include("header.inc");
            include("top_nav.inc");
        ?>
        <img src="ATD-Logo.jpg" alt="A Touch of Dazzle Home Page" style="width: 80%; height: auto;"/>
        <?
            include("footer.inc");
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The css stylesheet is working for both the header and top_nav files but not the footer. They are all formatted the exact same way. I put my css through a css3 validator and there were no mistakes.

Why is it only connecting to some?

(I have tried resaving it and opening and closing it and reopening it in the browser numerous times)

Here is the rest of the code for reference:

header.inc

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>A Touch of Dazzle</h1>
    <h3>Inventory Database</h3>
</div>
```

top_nav.inc

```
<div id="top_nav">
     <ul id="menu_nav">
        <li><a href="">Page One</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page Five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page Six</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

footer.inc

```
<div id="footer">
    <p>HomePage</p>
    <p>Name</p>
    <p>&copy; 2016</p>
</div>
```

The stylesheet obviously connects since parts of it are connecting. it's long but here is the part thats not connecting

```
/*main page begins*/
#main_page img
{
    margin-left: 10%;
 }
/*main page ends*/
/*footer begins*/
#footer p
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: red;
}
/*footer ends*/
```

Comment: i think styles arenot overridden/applied. try using !important like  color: red !important;

Comment: I stitched all the code together and the `#footer p` rule is applying to footer: http://i.imgur.com/a4ojhpk.png

Comment: @metarmask yeah i know it should work i just included the code so you would realize there is no problem with the code. My question is why my browser is not connecting them

Comment: @sumeetDarade thanks for the answer but unfortunately that still doesn't help

Comment: In that case, can you provide an example that does demonstrate the problem? Preferably as a snippet here in the question. Since the code you are showing works as intended, the problem must be with code not shown!

Comment: inspect the footer element and post a screenshot that would help debugging

Comment: @MrLister all code works. here are the parts that are relevant

Comment: @MrLister most of the stylesheet is for other pages of the website

Comment: Is the website live yet? Is there no way we can get to see the actual problem in action?

Comment: @MrLister sorry its on a localhost

Comment: Have you checked the source code after running it in your browser? Please try to inspect the particular section and check everything is rendered properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found after much research the best way was to force the browser to use my latest stylesheet by writing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css?v=1.1" />
```

Thank you everyone for your help, and if you find a better way to do this please let me know.